# Is there a Yammer REST api to monitor user login and logout activities

Tags: yammer

Does any of the Yammer REST api (like messages.json or export api) provide support to retrieve users login and logout activities?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API like this for Yammer. Yammer is part of a bigger product (O365) and there may be APIs or admin tools for that platform that can help with auditing.